# Executing the returned from an echo command in Windows. (if it is a executable file)

Tags: echo, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a program as administrator using the Command prompt in Windows.

```
C:\Users\i309\Desktop>set new=whoami.exe

C:\Users\i309\Desktop>%new%

global\i309

C:\Users\i309\Desktop>echo %new%

whoami.exe

C:\Users\i309\Desktop>
```

Why doesn't the "new" variable have the value global\i309?

My next step will be using the command

```
/runas /user:%new% /noprofile "application.exe"
```

When I run the above command, the "new" variable gets replaced to whoami.exe instead of my username. So it asks for the password of "whoami.exe", which is obviously not pertinent.

what could be the solution? Can this be solved using any piping method?

Answer (score 0):

The `set` command is quite literal.

To set a value to the result of a command, use

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('whoami.exe') do set "new=%%a"
```

See

```
for /?
```

Note : use `%%a` if this is being executed within a batch file. Use `%a` instead if this is being executed directly from the prompt.
from the prompt for documentation